# Updating Android seekbar Efficiently by emitting values from socket.io

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io

I'm developing an app in android in which i need to update seekbar from values given by server. how can i efficiently emit those values.

the Android app is about streaming songs from server. on server side i have used node.js with socket.io for bidirectional communication, 
Now i need to update the seekbar of all the clients who are listening to the song.
The problem is i'm emitting values in a room that broadcasts the values to all clients in that room.
Broadcasting every secs. seems to be a problem when there are multiple clients connected to the server.
How can i achieve this efficiently.
Thank you.

Comment: This is the forum from where you are expecting the answer, please articulate the question properly.

Comment: Why is broadcasting to all clients a problem? Socket.io broadcast in a room is as effecient as you are going to make it.

Comment: Sorry, but what am i missing?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Broadcasting every secs. seems to be a problem when there are multiple clients connected to the server."?

Comment: thanks,Dylan but the thing is that i need to broadcast values every seconds to 100s of clients. that is too in one room. i have multiple rooms like that will do the same

Comment: "Broadcasting every secs. seems to be a problem when there are multiple clients connected to the server." means that the seekbar need to be updated every seconds on client side from server. and there are multiple clients are connected in a room and also i have multiple rooms.